# Lookup is not picking up duplicate value

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

[image]I am trying to load a flat file to SQL table. I am using Slowly Changing Dimension to update existing rows and insert new ones.
I have also used a "LOOKUP" to ensure only new rows are inserted.

My table has only two colums

SORD - Primary key (Varchar(50))

CHGAMT - Float

However my ETL is failing as it is not picking up the matched row.

I have done this for at least 10 other imports and all work ok. However with this particular file and table, I am unable to "insert" new records because of existing primary key. However Lookup should be able to identify this and stop it from happening.

Here is the error message:

> [Insert Destination [33]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E2F.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E2F  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E2F  Description: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint '********'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object '******'. The duplicate key value is (OR14878029).".

I know what the error is but I dont know why the value is not being picked up by Lookup and sent to "Matched Rows" instead of "Un Matched Rows" path.

Comment: how is this `lookup` defined ?

Comment: When using full caching, SSIS compares strings in-memory according to the .NET rules, which means it matches every character by ordinal. SQL Server's rules match strings according to the collation (often case-insensitive) and it will ignore trailing blanks (as required by SQL). This is a common source of mismatches where SSIS will think a value is "new" and SQL Server disagrees.

Comment: It is making sense but how do I fix this please? I am not an expert so sorry if it is a noob question.

Comment: To check if this might be the issue, find the lookup operator and check if it's running in "full cache" mode. If so, try it by setting it to "none" and writing a query for the lookup -- then everything is done according to SQL rules. This can have (very) negative effects on the lookup performance, though (because every row now requires its own query) and if that's an issue you will need to normalize the values before lookup instead (trim all spaces, uppercase the string).

Comment: Thanks, I have done what you suggested. The SQL in the LOOKUP goes like this select * from (select * from ****) [refTable]
where [refTable].[SORD] = ?  do I need to change anything here? I did not work just by going to no cache mode

Comment: The weird thing is that the value OR14878029 is not even present in my text file.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a scenario where you have two duplicate rows from the source. one just inserted into the destination table and at the same time, another duplicate row gets passed from the lookup task. 
To fix this, you can use the Sort Transformation task which will remove the duplicate values from the source.

[image: Sort Transformation task in SSIS]